# Selenium does not mimic chrome behaviour

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to use selenium to get to the cached version of some websites. Unfortunaly, I'm not getting the same results as in Chrome.

When I go to chrome and enter:"cache:[https://www.nytimes.com/"](https://www.nytimes.com/%22), I'm immediately redirected to: "http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.nytimes.com%2F&rlz=1C5CHFA_enAR1034AR1034&oq=cache%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.nytimes.com%2F&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyBggAEEUYOTIGCAEQRRg60gEIMzI2MWowajSoAgCwAgA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8"

This is exactly what I expect.

When I use `driver.get("cache:https://www.nytimes.com/")`, I'm not getting redirected to that page at all.

Any clues what I might be missing? Many thanks!

EDIT:

I'm trying the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

try:
   link = driver.get("cache:https://www.nytimes.com/")
   time.sleep(5)
   print(driver.page_source)
 except Exception as X:
    print(X)

 driver.close()
```

I'm getting:

```
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

Comment: the get method has a validator which validates the URL, it's possible it's failing there.  Try/catch the call and include the exception in your post, if thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Selenium doesn't support `cache:` call in url.

However, you can write your own query that reaches Google cache endpoint with url as param.

Current endpoint is `ttps://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search` and cache param query is `q=cache:{url}`

```py
def open_cached_url(driver, url):
    driver.get(f"https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:{url}")

open_cached_url(driver, "https://www.example.com")
```